# simple cipher function, formatting the output

Tags: python, encryption

I wrote a little cipher program to use to send fun secret messages, it works pretty well but I want to change the output slightly. The code as is

```
base_alfa = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", " "]

shift_4_alfa = ["e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "a", "b", "c", "d", " "]

def encrypt_4(text):
    alfa_dir = []
    encrypted_text = []
    for i in text:
        if i in base_alfa:
            alfa_dir.append(base_alfa.index(i))
    for j in alfa_dir:
        encrypted_text.append(shift_8_alfa[j])
    return "".join(encrypted_text)
```

will print the characters with the exact same spacing. e.g. encrypt("this is difficult to read") == "xlmw mw hmjjmgypx xs vieh"

what I would like is for the output to regroup the characters in groups of five, like so: "xlmwm whmjj mgypx svieh"

any ideas on the best way to achieve this?

Comment: There's a problem with the regrouping idea. How will you decrypt it later? Though it is not hard to do, but there's a significant loss of information and decrypting will be much much harder.

Comment: It's OK though, if you are converting words just to make some game for kids who will manually try to figure out the original text. Not suitable for actual programs/modules interacting with each other.

Comment: the text won't be parsed to any other programs, it's simply for generating coded messages. I already have a decrypt function written that would revert the coded message back to plain text. If the coded message were grouped in fives, the decoded message would be also, which is part of the fun. This project was inspired by my dad who used a similar method when he was in the Navy.

Comment: Well this is one of the simplest encryption tool - and only for fun purposes. Your decrypt function will decrypt the string in groups of 5 - which would still not make any sense till you shift the spaces to form the correct words. e.g. "thisi sdiff icult torea d" Now a human can shift them based on their English knowledge but this is not technically decryption - you didn't arrive at original string. And this is a damn hard algorithmic problem. So, good for kids' or family games - but not practical. You didn't mention this though.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
groups = []
group = []
for c in "xlmw mw hmjjmgypx xs vieh".replace(" ", ""):
    group.append(c)
    if len(group) == 5:
        groups.append("".join(group))
        group = []
if group:
    groups.append("".join(group))
print(" ".join(groups))
```